# AIDE: marven libraries can't be downloaded

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, libraries

I'm trying to import android support v7 app library

I succeeded compiling in the build.gradle =>

[gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCGrZ.jpg)

But the (support) and (AppCompatActivity) are still undefined in MainActivity.java

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PevW9.jpg)
When I open properties of project I dont find any library. 
[libraries list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM1Eq.jpg)
And any modify I do to the parents in style.xml gives me Error!! 
I wish you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this on your build.gradle module app.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Also try to restart android studio by "Invalidate Cache and restart"